# renderAs PDF shows blank first page

Tags: visualforce, attachment, pdf, html2canvas, css3

I am using the [html2canvas library](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html) to render the page with a view to rendering the canvas as a PDF.  I am saving the canvas as an Attachment fine.  The direct link to the attachment looks like this:

[image]

without any margin or padding.  But when I render it as a PDF there is always a blank first page like so:

[image]

I tried adding the margin attribute to the @page but it had no effect.  Is there any way to prevent this blank page from appearing?  Here's the VF code, the controller just sets the Attachment ID.

```
<apex:page controller="toPdf" renderAs="pdf"  applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" cache="false">

<html>
   <head>
    <style>
    @page{
       size: A4 landscape;
       margin: 0in;
    }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <apex:image value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!attId}"  width="1024px"/>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I've encountered the same problem.  I was able to shift the blank page to the end of the printout by tinkering  with the ".page-break" section of my CSS, but I could not get rid of the page break.

Comment: Do you mean page-break-before: avoid?

Comment: I'm currently using "page-break-after:always;".  I'll have to experiment with "avoid" to see what happens.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the fix !
Could you please also tell me all the 'actions' (buttons/something) which you added to reach the PDF page from the 1st HTML calendar/page?

Comment: Also the image is not so good in the renderAs=pdf ! 

it looks a bit blurry in the PDF page.

But when I print the PDF page, it looks great as the original good quality image !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using the following on the apex:image styleClass:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
```

and it did the trick.